# ¿Como cambiar el value de un boton una vez clickeado?

Tags: javascript, html, web

Buenos dias,recien estoy empezando con javascript y me esta costando un poquito...
Lo que quiero hacer es que al hacer click al boton este cambie su value,pero no entiendo el error:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Hola mundo</title>
    <script src="holamundo_ext.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Hola" id="boton" onclick="cambiarboton()">
</body>
</html>
```

```js
function cambiarboton(){
    var i=document.getElementById("boton").innerHTML("Mundo");

}
window.onload=cambiarboton();
```

En la consola dice:

> TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
>   TypeError: document.getElementById(...).innerHTML is not a function

Desde ya,gracias!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`innerHTML` no es una funcion, sino una propiedad por lo que tienes que asignarla. `innerHTML` le asigna un string o objeto html al elemento seleccionado pero un `button` no acepta html. Lo que buscas es cambiar el `value`(valor), no el HTML:

```js
function cambiarboton(){
    var i=document.getElementById("boton").value = "Mundo";

}
window.onload=cambiarboton();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Hola mundo</title>
    <script src="holamundo_ext.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Hola" id="boton" onclick="cambiarboton()">
</body>
</html>
```

---

Siguiendo tu ejemplo y esta respuesta, el valor del buton se cambia al momento de la pagina cargar y seguro lo que quieres es que cambie el valor cuando se haga clic sobre el button. Elimina la declaracion de ejecutar una funcion cuando la pagina cargue:

```js
function cambiarboton(){
    var i=document.getElementById("boton").value = "Mundo";

}

// no se necesesita ya que se cambiara cuando se haga clic
//window.onload=cambiarboton();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Hola mundo</title>
    <script src="holamundo_ext.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Hola" id="boton" onclick="cambiarboton()">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Solo tener en cuenta, no tiene sentido el evento onload si lo quieres hacer onclick, del código sobraría `window.onload=cambiarboton();`

Comment: @jonilgz Si. Estaba actualizando mi respuesta dando a notar eso.

Answer (score 1):

**Para cambiar el contenido de un elemento HTML** desde JavaScript se usa la propiedad `.innerHTML = "";`

Es decir tu función `cambiarBoton()` debe quedar de la siguiente forma.

```
function cambiarboton(){
    var i=document.getElementById("boton").innerHTML = "Mundo";

}
```

En la ultima linea de tu código estableces la siguiente **escucha**...

```
window.onload=cambiarboton();
```

Esto quiere decir que cuando se hayan **cargado** todos los componentes de la ventana, se ejecutara la función `cambiarBoton()`

Pero ademas estas llamando a la misma función cada vez que **pulsas** el boton.

```
onclick="cambiarboton()"
```

Si lo que buscas es cambiar el valor al pulsar el botón debes dejar esta ultima y eliminar la escucha al evento `onload` de la ventana.